# Additivity of the Chi-squared distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Can additivity of the $\chi^2$-distribution be used when substracting variables?

For example:

Does X-Y=Z where X~$\chi^2$(3),  Y~$\chi^2$(1), Z~$\chi^2$(2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X-Y<0)>0$, whereas $P(Z<0)=0$. Thus the answer is negative.